# averageifs w/ multiple average ranges in different columns

Tags: arrays, excel, date, range, multiple-columns

=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS('Journal Input'!$AO$4:$AO$480,'Journal Input'!$O$4:$O$480,">="&F10,'Journal Input'!$O$4:$O$480,"<="&EOMONTH(F10,0)),"N/A")

This formula works but I need multiple average ranges added to this equation. My first average data range is AO but I have others in different columns (BB, BM, etc.) I would like to average along w/ AO. My multiple criteria's cover the beginning and end of the month F10. Perhaps an array is necessary? Any help is appreciated. Thanks Mike [Link to picture example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PydP1.jpg)

Comment: what have you tried to add the multiple average ranges? And can you give us an example of what your data might look like? Are you trying to add together the averages of the four columns? What would your end product ideally look like?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help. I have tried to add other ranges to the equation but get an error message. I edited the post and posted a picture to help solve this problem. I need the monthly averages calculated based upon the start and end dates of the month. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple options. Enter this as an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(IF(('Journal Input'!$O$4:$O$480>=F10)*('Journal Input'!$O$4:$O$480<=EOMONTH(F10,0)),CHOOSE({1,2,3},'Journal Input'!$AO$4:$AO$480,'Journal Input'!$BB$4:$BB$480,'Journal Input'!$BM$4:$BM$480))),"N/A")
```

Or, since it's the same conditions for all columns, you can average the `AVERAGEIFS` of each column (this doesn't need to be entered as an array formula):

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(AVERAGEIFS('Journal Input'!$AO$4:$AO$480,'Journal Input'!$O$4:$O$480,">="&F10,'Journal Input'!$O$4:$O$480,"<="&EOMONTH(F10,0)),AVERAGEIFS('Journal Input'!$BB$4:$BB$480,'Journal Input'!$O$4:$O$480,">="&F10,'Journal Input'!$O$4:$O$480,"<="&EOMONTH(F10,0)),AVERAGEIFS('Journal Input'!$BM$4:$BM$480,'Journal Input'!$O$4:$O$480,">="&F10,'Journal Input'!$O$4:$O$480,"<="&EOMONTH(F10,0))),"N/A")
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help. I tried using the Choose function before but couldn't get it to work. But your syntax for the choose worked perfectly! Thanks again for the help. Mike